# Duplex connection with SOAP 1.1 service

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I wish to connect to a SOAP 1.1 service. The service specifies a callback interface so I must connect using the duplex wcf classes.

My problem is that basicHttpBinding is SOAP11, but does not allow duplex.
wsDualHttpBinding allows duplex, but is strictly SOAP12

I can clarify more if there is any questions, but how do I do this seemingly simple thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a custom binding with messageVersion set to Soap11WSAddressing10. You can see mine here. Be warned though that im' not quite finished debugging it:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="SomeCustomerApi" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" allowInsecureTransport="true"/>
          <compositeDuplex clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:port"/>
          <oneWay maxAcceptedChannels="2"/>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" writeEncoding="utf-8"/>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          authenticationScheme="Negotiate"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          transferMode="Buffered"
          manualAddressing="false"
                         />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```